# Error when upgrading SpringBoot from 2.1.1 to 2.1.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application with SpringBoot version `2.1.1.RELEASE`. I tried to upgrade it to the latest version: `2.1.2.RELEASE`. Now I get an error in initialisation. Does something has to change in the source? I saw that the Spring version is upgraded from `5.1.3.RELEASE` to `5.1.4.RELEASE`, but I wasn't expecting changes that will break the application by just a minor upgrade.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/ResolvableType;Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)V from class org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.getTypeDescriptor(DependencyDescriptor.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest for you to check the release note for those particular release to see if there is any breaking changes that would affect your application

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace as well as your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end it was an fixed dependency to spring-core 5.1.3.RELEASE. This caused the error.